# How to get unread notifications (2 tables with FK)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, notifications

I have 2 tables on my DB: `user_notification` and `user_notification_read`. It's a user notification system, the notifications are on `user_notification` and when a user reads a notification, it stores on `user_notification_read` with the notification `id` and the user `id`.

```
CREATE TABLE `user_notification` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `related_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `text` text NOT NULL,
 `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `user_notification_read` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `notification_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `notification_id` (`notification_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `user_notification_read_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`notification_id`) REFERENCES `user_notification` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to make a SELECT to **get the number of unread notifications for a certain user** *(by the user id)*.

I thought about using a

`JOIN/WHERE` (`notification.id = user_notification_read.notification_id` and `user_notification.user_id = X`)to get the rows from `user_notification_read` with a `CASE` to check if the row exists. If it doesn't exists, +1 on unread notifications.

I don't know if that's the appropriate logic to achieve it and don't know the syntax as well. I tried some google, but the examples are more complex than my case, which I believe it's simple.

How can I do that?

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84a5ed/5/0

On the fiddle example, the  count for unread notifications would be **2** for the user **1**.

Comment: I can think of `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS`, and `LEFT JOIN` with a `WHERE` clause.  Have you figured out the solution yet?

Comment: I think you got the answer. I would like to say something else, IMO adding 'is_read' to the 'user_notification' was the best way to achieve this. Set default to '0' and update to '1' on read event. No need of these queries.

Comment: @AneesSadeek that's true (I've done it before) but what would be the best way to do it? There's a lot of ways to do a lot of things, I'm always in doubt what would be the best way to do something when it's not too obvious (fastness, readability, etc).

Comment: Me too.. That's a good thing, that keeps improving your skill and knowledge. 'Find it yourself :)' think about your project and make a decision. In normal scenario I don't prefer this. If notification table needs that much care, do it like this. Even though I prefer to write entry with notification and update unless the number of notifications is that much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `left join`.

```
SELECT sum(r.notification_id is null)
FROM user_notification n
LEFT JOIN user_notification_read r ON r.notification_id = n.id
WHERE n.user_id = 1
```

`r.notification_id is null` means a notification wasn't read.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I tested this and `NOT EXISTS` as suggested by @gordon-linoff and `NOT EXISTS` is performing faster on my server, so I'll use it.